# Signal value not yet sent! shown on CANoe panel

Tags: panel, capl, canoe

I'm trying to get the value from track bar to update a variable `original_threshold` in CAPL.
I've been getting this issue in the CANoe panel.
After reading a few posts, it seems like I missed the IL to send the value of this track bar.

[Signal value not yet sent! shown on track bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1CaY.png) /
[current properties of the track bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w85Zg.png)

There're a few attempt that I've tried to build the IL but did not work.

a. create an event handler on sysvar test::threshold

```
on sysvar test::threshold{
   original_threshold = @test::threshold;
}
```

b. create a cyclic timer to update the value every 200ms

```
variables{
   msTimer cyclicTimer200ms;
}
on start{
   setTimerCyclic(cyclicTimer200ms, 200);
}
on timer cyclicTimer200ms
{
    original_threshold = @test::threshold;
}
```

c. using an update button to update the track bar value

```
on sysvar test::button_clicked{
   if(@test::button_clicked == 1){
     original_threshold = @test::threshold;
   }
}
```

None of them work.
`Signal value not yet sent!` is still there whenever I adjust the track bar.
I'm wondering what am I missing out on.
Hope someone who is more familiar with CANoe could give me a hint. Thank you!